# Not able to save the system file in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, centos

Whenever i save the system file(under manage jenkins) i encounter this error. in the logs it say this.

```
Jan 05, 2024 6:49:08 AM WARNING hudson.init.impl.InstallUncaughtExceptionHandler handleException
Caught unhandled exception with ID e5ee1136-cc3a-42b4-b54a-8dc5894675f2
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The frontend sent an unexpected list of classes (["hudson.maven.local_repo.DefaultLocalRepositoryLocator","hudson.maven.local_repo.PerExecutorLocalRepositoryLocator","hudson.maven.local_repo.PerJobLocalRepositoryLocator"]) rather than an expected single class. See https://www.jenkins.io/doc/developer/views/table-to-div-migration/ for more information.
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl$TypePair.convertJSON(RequestImpl.java:750)
Caused: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to instantiate class hudson.maven.local_repo.LocalRepositoryLocator from {"stapler-class":["hudson.maven.local_repo.DefaultLocalRepositoryLocator","hudson.maven.local_repo.PerExecutorLocalRepositoryLocator","hudson.maven.local_repo.PerJobLocalRepositoryLocator"],"$class":["hudson.maven.local_repo.DefaultLocalRepositoryLocator","hudson.maven.local_repo.PerExecutorLocalRepositoryLocator","hudson.maven.local_repo.PerJobLocalRepositoryLocator"]}
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl$TypePair.convertJSON(RequestImpl.java:771)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl.bindJSON(RequestImpl.java:551)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl.bindJSON(RequestImpl.java:546)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSet$DescriptorImpl.configure(MavenModuleSet.java:1441)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.configureDescriptor(Jenkins.java:4097)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.doConfigSubmit(Jenkins.java:4061)
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(MethodHandle.java:710)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$MethodFunction.invoke(Function.java:397)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:409)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:207)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.SelectionInterceptedFunction$Adapter.invoke(SelectionInterceptedFunction.java:36)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.verb.HttpVerbInterceptor.invoke(HttpVerbInterceptor.java:48)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.SelectionInterceptedFunction.bindAndInvoke(SelectionInterceptedFunction.java:26)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:140)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$11.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:558)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:59)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:770)"
```

anyone has any idea how to solve this?????

Comment: It says: "rather than an expected single class. See https://www.jenkins.io/doc/developer/views/table-to-div-migration/ for more information.", which suggests you have updated Jenkins or a Plugin across the 2.263.4/2.277.1 tables-to-dive breaking changes. Read the link and update accordingly, or remove the incompatible plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I updated all Jenkins plugins, and now it's working. The issue has been resolved.